# how to use cursorAdapter to support multiple row layout of the list view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

Running into the situation that the listView's row will need to display different number of the record data from the cursor (i.e. one listView's row could contain multiple record rows from the cursor).

Or that the cursor.getCount() is not same as the listView expected list data count. 
For example, cursor has 100 record rows, the listView needs to show in such a way the first 10 listView rows are each with 3 cursor records and rest will show 2 cursor records in the lisView's row. So the listView expects to have total 10 + 35 = 45 rows (10x3 + 35x2 =100) although the cursor has 100 records.

Seems bindView() and newView() are given the cursor corresponding to the viewList's row position.
How to group the cursor records into either a three or two for one listView row?

```
@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
... 
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
...
}
```

Comment: You can transport the Cursor data to an ArrayList, and then use a ArrayAdapter in place of the CursorAdapter.

Comment: Remember that, when transferring the data to the ArrayList you should group the way you want. Because the ListView displays a position of the ArrayList per row.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. when translate from cursor to list/array, it seems has impact on the performance, the cursor has over 20000 rows of record, and need the cursorAdapter to reflect the database data change dynamically.

Comment: I get it. But unfortunately I do not see how to hack the CursorAdapter to group the information. Because it is programmed to print line by line. Perhaps the solution for you is to load data "on demand". Load 20,000 records is not a good idea in any environment.